# How to extract x-atmosphere-tracking-id from a string?

Tags: regex, jmeter, regex-lookarounds, vaadin7, regex-group

I am trying to extract X-Atmosphere-tracking-id from the response body.
I got the response in the following way:

```
40|41be6f15-2e19-4e1d-aaff-d4b92ae47e48|0||
```

Now I want to extract only:

```
41be6f15-2e19-4e1d-aaff-d4b92ae47e48
```

which is dynamically generated on every execution.

Also, It would be great if someone shares tips and tricks as well as reference videos/sites of load testing using JMeter for Vaading application.

Comment: If you need assistance with JMeter ask about JMeter specific. If you need assistance with Vaading ask about Vaading specific. I suggesting taking online courses for both products.

Comment: DudiBoy, thanks for your guidance. I am currently working on a project having Vaadin and Apache JMeter both. That is the reason I have added both tags. Please let me know in case, some modification is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we might just want to simply use a list of chars:

```
(?:\|)([a-z0-9-]+)(?:\|)
```

The string that we wish to extract is in this capturing group:

```
([a-z0-9-]+)
```

with two boundaries in its left and right side:

```
(?:\|)
```

---

Based on [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)'s advice, we can also simplify our expression and remove the non-capturing groups:

```
\|([a-z0-9-]+)\|
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QxxaTr/1)

Comment: You could write `\|` instead of using a non capturing group `(?:\|)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using simple awk script, parsing fields by `|` and extracting the 2nd field.

```
echo "40|41be6f15-2e19-4e1d-aaff-d4b92ae47e48|0||" | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'
```

Output

```
41be6f15-2e19-4e1d-aaff-d4b92ae47e48
```